# How can I do more optimal async/await using inside loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, optimization

I want to do more optimal my code. I summeries to following code.I have a data access layer named 
ICDataAccess.I making that get all inventorys firts line.Then I get locations of inventory response and I want to get all barcodes with locations information from ServiceCaller data access.Then *this barcodes* adds to each inventory of inventorys array.How can i do more optimal.Is there a logic error. Help me please...

```js
   const ic = await this.ICDataAccess.getActiveIC({ warehouse, locations, status: statuses }); // An object array
    await Promise.all(ic.map(async (item) => {
      const inventory = item;
      const response = await ServiceCaller.filterStore({ ids: inventory.locations, fields: 'barcode' }); // An object array
      inventory.barcodes = response.map(res =>res.barcode);
    }));
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You're mistaken. The callback passed to `ic.map` is `async` and so will return a Promise. In this case the Promise will resolve to `undefined`, but this code is correct insofar as the promise returned by `Promise.all` will resolve (to an array of `undefined`s) once all of those promises resolve.

Comment: Ah, yes good point.

Comment: @JordanRunning just wondering, would this implementation wait for each call to `ServiceCaller.filterStore` to resolve before continuing to the next item?

Comment: No. Once the code hits `await` it is free to jump and continue from where the `async` function was declared, so it will run the first one, see await, jump to the next item in the array, run that, see await, etc. At some point, the first `ServiceCaller.filterStore` will return and execution of the first function will be picked up again, so while the call order is almost certainly 0,1,2,3,... those are not "blocked" by the previous one finishing.

Comment: (e.g. `Promise.all([0,1,2,3,4].map(async(v) => { console.log(v); await new Promise(_ => setTimeout(_, Math.random()*1000)); console.log(v+'d'); }));`)

Comment: "*Is there a logic error?*" - only you can tell. You designed the logic, you know whether it works as expected or not.

Comment: You should simplify to `inventory.barcodes = response.map(res => res.barcode);`, but that has nothing to do with `async`/`await`.

Comment: @Bergi you're right.ı will revise.Thanks for you contribution

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans,Then wrong barcodes can be assigned to inventories during the resolve.Am i right? Because response of first resolved promise assigned to current inventory.

Comment: @HarunKELEŞOĞLU No, they can't. Each inventory gets assigned its own barcodes. The order in which the promises resolve does not matter.

Comment: Thanks again @Bergi
I have written nice code then :D . I'll do a little more practice on this

Comment: Your code can be even nicer if you drop the `item` variable and just name your function parameter `inventory` :-)